# Issue with loading Web App in Opera Mini

Tags: javascript, web-applications, opera-mini

Can anyone please tell me how to switch from Extreme Mode to High Mode in Opera Mini via JavaScript?

Comment: We are making a progressive app. It works well in normal mode but it kind of gets messed up in Extreme Mode (Mini browsers). We are looking for a solution to fix it, but haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Extreme` and `High` modes are browser settings.

You can't change browser settings by using JavaScript. That would be a pretty big security concern if you were able to do that.